# Geospatial Analysis

Tags: qgis, matlab

[image]How can I convert spatial information like the elevation, land use(source:corine land cover map), location of power transmission lines, etc to a 2D array of numbers like a  2D spatial array based on latitude/longitude, with input parameters to specify the minimum and maximum desired latitude and longitude, as well as the desired spacing between the points in the 2D array?
For example how can i convert the image(land use) into a matrix/array and get information for each point. [image]

Answer (score 2):

> 2D spatial array based on latitude/longitude, with input parameters to specify the minimum and maximum desired latitude and longitude, as well as the desired spacing between the points in the 2D array

The data format you describe is a geolocated / georeferenced / geospatial raster. In the GIS world, it's just referred to as [raster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics#Geographic_information_systems) data. Raster data comes in many formats, and can be obtained from many sources. If you need to obtain raster data, [the `geospatial` tag on Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial) is a good place to start.

Any GIS software (including QGIS) can view, process and manipulate geospatial raster data in the ways you describe. Have a look at the [Working with Raster Data](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/index.html) section of the QGIS Manual to get started.

Answer (score 0):

At first, most of those analysis are performed originally in planar coordinates like UTM, and for that reason you must be aware if your data is originally in geographic coordinates.

There are many ways to convert an raster image to a matrix. Some requires basic programming othes can be made by performing a series of data translation to simpler formats.

One of this is to convert the raster to point data and save it as an ascii grid and then try to arrange that information in a matrix like you whant.

Other way is to convert the raster to csv format. You will have tree columns: x,y, value and then again you will look for a method to arrange the information in a matrix.

Anyway, if your raster image have too many columns and rows, I think the task will be very complicated in terms of the quantity of data you have to see.

Comment: What if the file is a shapefile, will it be possible to do it on Matlab?

Comment: First of all I wrongly supossed you are working with a raster data. What you can do is convert that data to raster and follow all the indications I gave or construct a grid composed by points separated by a specific space and make a intersection with your polygon shapefile & the point shapefile in order to transfer the polygon information to the points. And then convert to ascii & get the data. That is in theory, but the implementation in general follows this way. I am not sure if you can do this process with matlab but I think it is possible with other similar packages like ScyPython, R.

Comment: I tried converting it into a raster but unfortunately was not able to get the information of all the points. Is there any simple way to convert the vector layer into a raster

Comment: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html